# State within useEffect not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm currently building a timer in ReactJS for practice. Currently I have two components, a `Timer` component which displays the time as well as sets an interval upon mounting. I also have an `App` component which keeps tracks of the main state, such as state for whether the timer is `paused` as well as the current value of the `timer`.

My goal is to make it so that when I click the `pause` button, the timer stops incrementing. Currently I've tried to achieve this by using:

```
if(!paused) 
  tick(time => time+1);
```

which in my mind, should only increment the `time` state when `paused` is `false`. However, when I update the `paused` state by clicking on my button, this `paused` state inside the setTimeout does not change. My guess that setTimeout is forming a closure over the `paused` state, so it's not updating when the state changes. I tried adding `paused` as a dependency to `useEffect` but this caused multiple timeouts to be queued whenever `paused` changed.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Timer = ({time, paused, tick}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if(!paused) // `paused` doesn't change?
        tick(time => time+1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  return <p>{time}s</p>
}

const App = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
  const togglePaused = () => setPaused(paused => !paused);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Timer paused={paused} time={time} tick={setTime} />
      <button onClick={togglePaused}>{paused ? 'Play' : 'Pause'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So, my question is:

1. Why isn't my current code working (why is `paused` not updating within `useEffect`)?
2. Is there any way to make the above code work so that I can "pause" my interval which is set within the `useEffect()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop the timer return the function clearing the interval from `useEffect()`.

> React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.
>
> (source: [Using the Effect Hook - Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup))

You should also pass the `paused` in dependencies array to stop `useEffect` creating new intervals on each re-render. If you add `[paused]` it'll only create new interval when `paused` change.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Timer = ({time, paused, tick}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if(!paused) // `paused` doesn't change?
        tick(time => time+1);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [paused]);
 
  return <p>{time}s</p>
}

const App = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
  const togglePaused = () => setPaused(paused => !paused);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Timer paused={paused} time={time} tick={setTime} />
      <button onClick={togglePaused}>{paused ? 'Play' : 'Pause'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ah! I like this! 

Comment: Wouldn't this re-run the useEffect each time setInterval set's the time?

Answer (score 2):

The setInterval captures the `paused` value the first time, you'll need to remove the interval, recreate it everytime paused is changed.

You can check this article for more info: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dan's `useInterval` hook. I can't explain it better than him [why](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) you should use this.

The hook looks like this.

```js
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = React.useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Then use it in your `Timer` component like this.

```js
const Timer = ({ time, paused, tick }) => {
  useInterval(() => {
    if (!paused) tick(time => time + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <p>{time}s</p>;
};
```

I believe the difference is that `useInterval` hook is aware of its dependencies (paused) while `setInterval` isn't.